# Android emulator not loading in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

I am having an issue loading my emulator. Using my AVD manager I create an AVD named Nexus whose location is `C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.android\avd` by default

When I try to launch my application however , I get this message in my console

```
[2012-07-03 17:57:48 - Emulator] PANIC: Could not open: C:\Users\ritika\.android/avd/Nexus.ini
```

My issue is how do I make the application point to the correct location where the avd folder is actually located.

Comment: your avd folder is in 'C:\Users\ritika\.android/avd/'

Comment: My avd folder by default is in C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.android\avd

Comment: Check this out, some of the solutions might help solve your problem. http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=19084

Comment: Thanks.There were some permission issues with the mentioned folders. I created a new folder and set the ANDROID_SDK_HOME environment variable value to the path of this folder.It works.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using the latest version of eclipse? And did you install the android pluging through eclipse? Perhaps you could try updating it or creating a different type of avd?

Answer (score 1):

On Windows 7 (64-bit):

Seems like Android Virtual Device manager [stupidly] creates the virtual device [related files] in `D:\userdata\<user-name>\.android` but while starting it, it looks for the device in `C:\Users\<user-name>\.android`

Anyway, I donno much abt Android [was trying to run Hello Wolrd :-)], but I just found that NTFS now supports links so I just created a link. In my case:

```
C:\Users\UserName> mklink /d .android D:\userdata\UserName\.android
symbolic link created for .android <<===>> D:\userdata\UserName\.android

C:\Users\UserName>
```

You'll probably have to run the `cmd` as admin, as I also am a dummy with Windows, I just went to `C:\Windows\System32`, right-clicked on cmd.exe and selected "Run as administrator". I'm sure there would be some `su` equivalent on windows.

In case you don't find your `D:\userdata\UserName\.android` then I recommend to just search your HDDs for `.android` and use that path instead of `D:\userdata\UserName\.android`.

Answer (score 0):

In your current user's documents directory (mine is on D:\Documents) you will find a `.android` folder. Inside it is a `avd` folder. It contains all AVD's. Copy it to `C:\Users\<user>\.android\`. This is a quick fix and has to be done every time you change any AVD.

The destination folder for the above question will be `C:\Users\ritika\.android\avd`